# Смена картинки при нажатии

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на картинку она менялась на следущую?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Смена картинок</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        var i=0;
        var image=document.getElementById("image");
        // Добавьте свои картинки в массив через запятую
        var imgs=new Array('img1.jpg','img2.jpg');
        function imgsrc() {
            i++;i%=imgs.length;
            image.src = imgs[i];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" src="" onClick="imgsrc();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если понимать вас буквально, то примерно вот так:

```
img.onclick = function() {
    img.src = 'next_image.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно перенести блок с скриптом в конец body. т.к. HTML страница рендерится по очереди кода. ниже пример где должно работать:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Смена картинок</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" src="note.png" onClick="imgsrc();">
    <script language="javascript">
        var i=0;
        var image=document.getElementById("image");
        // Добавте свои картинки через запятую
        var imgs=new Array('note.png','note_30.png', 'note_30_.png');
        function imgsrc() {
            i++;
            image.src=imgs[i];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```