# Скрипт по переключению картинок работает не корректно

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения

Скрипт от пользователя @Rules работает не корректно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/82340/358030

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at imgsrc (Shure N97ED.html:18)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (Shure N97ED.html:35)
```

Часть кода

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Электрон ул.Гоголя 115</title>
    <!-- Подключаем стиль -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
    <!-- Делаем ширину -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 

    <script language="javascript">
        var i=0;
        var image=document.getElementById("image");
        // Добавьте свои картинки в массив через запятую
        var imgs=new Array('Shure N97ED/image.jpg(1)','Shure N97ED/image(2).jpg');
        function imgsrc() {
            i++;i%=imgs.length;
            image.src = imgs[i];
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = page >

        <nav class = "navigation">
            <a class = "link" href = "#part1">Фотографии</a>
            <a class = "link" href = "#part2">О нас</a>
            <a class = "link" href = "#part3">Местоположение</a>
        </nav>
        <div class = "theme">
            <div class = "obavlenie1_in">
                <div class = "white_theme">

                    <img id = "image" src = "Shure N97ED/image.jpg" onClick = "imgsrc();">

                </div>

        </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>


</html>
```

Строение папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var i=0;
    //var image=document.getElementById("image");
    // Добавьте свои картинки в массив через запятую
    var imgs=new Array('Shure N97ED/image.jpg(1)','Shure N97ED/image(2).jpg');
    function imgsrc() {
        i++;i%=imgs.length;
        //image.src = imgs[i];
        document.getElementById("image").src = imgs[i];
    }
```

или

```
    <img id = "image" src = "Shure N97ED/image.jpg" onClick = "imgsrc(this);">

    var i=0;
    //var image=document.getElementById("image");
    // Добавьте свои картинки в массив через запятую
    var imgs=new Array('Shure N97ED/image.jpg(1)','Shure N97ED/image(2).jpg');
    function imgsrc(image) {
        i++;i%=imgs.length;
        image.src = imgs[i];
    }
```

или

```
    var i=0;
    var image;
    window.addEventListener('load', () => image=document.getElementById("image"));
```

или

```
    <img id = "image" src = "Shure N97ED/image.jpg" onClick = "imgsrc();">
    <script language="javascript">
      var i=0;
      var image=document.getElementById("image");
      ...
```

и так далее.